# Can you put two conditions in an xslt test attribute?

Tags: xslt

Is this right for When 4 < 5 and 1 < 2 ?

```
<xsl:when test="4 &lt; 5 AND 1 &lt; 2" >
<!-- do something -->
</xsl:when>
```

Comment: Operators and precedence: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256081(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 222, accepted):

Not quite, the AND has to be lower-case.

```
<xsl:when test="4 &lt; 5 and 1 &lt; 2">
<!-- do something -->
</xsl:when>
```

Answer (score 34):

It does have to be wrapped in an <xsl:choose> since it's a when.  And lowercase the "and".

```
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="4 &lt; 5 and 1 &lt; 2" >
   <!-- do something -->
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
   <!-- do something else -->
   </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 6):

From [XML.com](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/04/02/trxml.html):

> Like xsl:if instructions, xsl:when
>   elements can have more elaborate
>   contents between their start- and
>   end-tags—for example, literal result
>   elements, xsl:element elements, or
>   even xsl:if and xsl:choose elements—to
>   add to the result tree. Their test
>   expressions can also use all the
>   tricks and operators that the xsl:if
>   element's test attribute can use, such
>   as and, or, and function calls, to
>   build more complex boolean
>   expressions.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this is a no-brainer for the xslt-professional, but for me at beginner/intermediate level, this got me puzzled. I wanted to do exactly the same thing, but I had to test a responsetime value from an xml instead of a plain number. Following this thread, I tried this:

```
<xsl:when test="responsetime/@value &gt;= 5000 and responsetime/@value &lt;= 8999">
```

which generated an error. This works:

```
<xsl:when test="number(responsetime/@value) &gt;= 5000 and number(responsetime/@value) &lt;= 8999">
```

Don't really understand why it doesn't work without number(), though. Could it be that without number() the value is treated as a string and you can't compare numbers with a string?

Anyway, hope this saves someone a lot of searching...