# XSL If Statement possible to add AND?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have the following line I have used in the past to set a dashboard icon, how would I add another condition and if ttl_qsa_fin NE 0

```
<xsl:if test="normalize-space(@ttl_qsr_fin) = 0">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you put two conditions in an xslt test attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318875/can-you-put-two-conditions-in-an-xslt-test-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect unlike the possible dupe answer linked to, you're also not sure how to add the `not equals` operator to the IF test.

The complete answer for your scenario is:

```
<xsl:if test="(normalize-space(@ttl_qsr_fin) = 0) and not(ttl_qsa_fin = 0)">
```

As Michael Kay explains [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10536840/3617262), while you could also write the second filter condition as `!=`, that approach would require `ttl_qsa_fin` always be present in your source XML to evaluate as true. By using `not()` though, it also account for cases in which `ttl_qsa_fin` is absent in the source XML.

And to be safe, confirm the data type of both `ttl_qsr_fin` and `ttl_qsa_fin`; if they are strings (which is implied by the use of `normalize-space`), then the IF test conditions should have the values being tested for wrapped in single quotes:

```
<xsl:if test="(normalize-space(@ttl_qsr_fin) = '0') and not(ttl_qsa_fin = '0')">
```